# starting with flex - please let me know if the direction is right (ActionScript vs MXML separation)

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, flex3

I've just started learning flex using OReilly "Programming Flex 3.0". After completing three chapters and starting fourth (ActionScript), and not having enough patience to wait till completing chapter 22 I started to practice :)

One bit that I have most worries about right now is the the dual coding mode (MXML vs ActionScript)

Please have a look at my code below (it compiles via **mxmlc design.mxml**, second file 'code.as' should be in same directory) and advise if the separation I used between visual design and code is appropriate.

Also - **if some smart guy could show me how to recode same example with *.as being a class file [package?] it would be highly appreciated**. I got lost with creating directory structure for package - and did not find it most intuitive, especially for small project that has two files like my example.

---

Code: design.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
 <mx:Script source="code.as"/>
 <mx:VBox>
  <mx:TextInput creationComplete="initializeCalculator()" id="txtScreen"/>
  <mx:HBox>
   <mx:Button click="click('7')" id="btn7" label="7"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('8')" id="btn8" label="8"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('9')" id="btn9" label="9"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('C')" id="btnClear" label="C"/>
  </mx:HBox>
  <mx:HBox>
   <mx:Button click="click('4')" id="btn4" label="4"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('5')" id="btn5" label="5"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('6')" id="btn6" label="6"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('/')" id="btnDivide" label="/"/>
  </mx:HBox>
  <mx:HBox>
   <mx:Button click="click('1')" id="btn1" label="1"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('2')" id="btn2" label="2"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('3')" id="btn3" label="3"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('*')" id="btnMultiply" label="*"/>
  </mx:HBox>
  <mx:HBox>
   <mx:Button click="click('0')" id="btn0" label="0"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('=')" id="btnEqual" label="="/>
   <mx:Button click="click('-')" id="btnMinus" label="-"/>
   <mx:Button click="click('+')" id="btnPlus" label="+"/>
  </mx:HBox>
 </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

---

code: code.as

```
public var res:int = 0;
public var previousOperator:String = "";
public var previousRes:int=0;

public function initializeCalculator():void{
 txtScreen.text = res.toString();
}
public function click(code:String):void{ 
 if (code=="1" || code=="2" || code=="3" || code=="4" || code=="5" ||
   code=="6" || code=="7" || code=="8" || code=="9" || code=="0"){
  res = res*10 + int(code);
  txtScreen.text = res.toString();
 }
 else if (code=="C"){
  res = 0;
  previousOperator ="";
  previousRes = 0;
  txtScreen.text = res.toString();
 }
 else{
  calculate(code);
 }
}
public function calculate(operator:String):void{
 var tmpRes:int;
 if (previousOperator=="+"){
  tmpRes = previousRes + res;
 }
 else if (previousOperator=="-"){
  tmpRes = previousRes - res;
 }
 else if (previousOperator=="/"){
  tmpRes = previousRes / res;
 }
 else if (previousOperator=="*"){
  tmpRes = previousRes * res;
 }
else{
 tmpRes = res;
}
 previousOperator = operator;
 previousRes = tmpRes;
 txtScreen.text = previousRes.toString();
res = 0;
 if (previousOperator=="=")
 {
  res = tmpRes;
  txtScreen.text=res.toString();
 }
}
```

PS. If you have comments that this calculator does not calculate properly, they are also appreciated, yet most important are comments on best practices in Flex.

Answer (score 0):

This [example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/building_components_using_code_behind/) on using code-behind in a Flex application should be helpful in cleaning up the link between your user interface and the application logic.

Answer (score 0):

I normally write the code in a `CDATA` block inside the `<mx:script/>` tag itself.

```
<mx:Script source="code.as">
  <![CDATA[
    //code here
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

This is the way it is done in most of the tutorials and Adobe code samples out there. An mxml file represents an ActionScript `class` (the file design.mxml creates a class named `design` in the root package) and hence I believe it makes sense to put the whole code in one place (file) - this is a matter of choice though.

If user interface parts in a component are minimal, you can create that component using just an AS file. Checkout the code for a panel with a text input and a button in it:

```
//MyPanel.as inside /your/folder/structure
package your.folder.structure
{
  //import appropriate classes here
  public class MyPanel extends Panel
  {
    [Bindable]
    public var txt:TextInput;
    [Bindable]
    public var btn:Button;
    public function MyPanel(){}
    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
       txt = new TextInput();
       txt.text = "Default text";
       txt.setStyle("color", 0xffff00);
       addChild(txt);
       btn = new Button();
       btn.label = "Click me!"
       btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick);
       addChild(btn);
    }
    private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
      trace("clicked");
    }
  }
}
```

And the (almost) equivalent mxml code would be:

```
<!-- MyPanel.mxml inside /your/folder/structure -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Panel xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
  xmlns="your.folder.structure.*">
  <mx:TextInput id="txt" text="Default text" color="#ffff00"/>
  <mx:Button id="btn" label="Click me!" click="handleClick(event);"/>
  <mx:Script source="code.as">
    <![CDATA[
        private function handleClick(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
          trace("clicked");
        }
    ]]>
  </mx:Script>
</mx:Panel>
```